# Text-align:center property doesn't work how can ı fix it

Tags: html, css

I have 8 div and one of them is a parent element. I gave a display: flex property my parent, and ı wanna locate my all texts in the middle of my divs because of that ı use text-align property but it is doesn't work

```css
.social-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  left: 225px;
  top: 163px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-links">
    <div id="facebook" style="background-color: rgb(60,86,156);">Facebook</div>
    <div id="twitter" style="background-color: rgb(29,162,243);">Twitter</div>
    <div id="email" style="background-color: rgb(132,132,132);">Email</div>
    <div id="pinterest" style="background-color:rgb(199,33,39);">Pinterest</div>
    <div id="whatsapp" style="background-color:rgb(78,193,69);">Whatsapp</div>
    <div id="telegram" style="background-color:rgb(0,135,207);">Telegram</div>
    <div id="more" style="background-color:rgb(255,101,81); width: 91px; ;">+ More</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to work to me. I edited your question putting your code in a live snippet (to see it you'll have to wait for review first). The parent element is aligning its children to the center and each one of them has a width based on their contents. Their text is correctly aligned to the center. I removed the extra closing </div> that had no context and had to remove a couple of random backticks. To make it better you could style text-align on the inner divs.

Comment: You can't tell whether the text is centered because the width is defined by the text itself. Did you mean to add some padding and/or did you want each of the items to have the same width (with the texts centered)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
<div class="social-links" style=display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;>
 <div id="facebook" style="background-color: rgb(60,86,156);">Facebook</div>
 <div id="twitter" style="background-color: rgb(29,162,243);">Twitter</div>
 <div id="email" style="background-color: rgb(132,132,132);">Email</div>
 <div id="pinterest" style="background-color:rgb(199,33,39);">Pinterest</div>
 <div id="whatsapp" style="background-color:rgb(78,193,69);">Whatsapp</div>
 <div id="telegram" style="background-color:rgb(0,135,207);">Telegram</div>
 <div id="more" style="background-color:rgb(255,101,81); width: 91px; ;">+ More</div>


 </div>
```

Comment: The align attribute is deprecated and should not be used. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2

Comment: I see. But with my code it worked always.
The text-align atribute controls only text.

Comment: I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

it because when u display flex all the childs even though they are displayed block, flex will make them be displayed inline so it will take the minimum space instead of 100% width of the parent, so you need to give each child more width to see that the text is in the center of it's div

or if you want to display all the text in a row but center just add justify-content: center and align-items: center, these are for the parent

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I gave a display:inline-block property of all childs and line-height as much as all childs height

```css
.social-links div {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 27px;
}
```